# Is the output of Gson.toJson repeatable on Map datatype

Tags: java, json, gson

Say I've the following code snippet.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
SortedMap<String,String> m = new TreeMap<String,String>();
m.put("a", "apple");
m.put("b", "box");
gson.toJson(m)
```

The above code would output

```
{"a":"apple","b":"box"}
```

Am I guaranteed to get the same string back if I execute the code block say 100k times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. TreeMap entries are sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys and gson will simply iterate through the key set.